# Detecting Line feeds with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to detect standalone line feeds within a file with Python. The file has some standalone "LF" (i.e. \n) and some "CRLF" (i.e. \r\n) combinations and I'm trying to just match to the standalone ones.

I thought this would work:

```
match = re.search('(?<!\r)\n', line)
```

where `line` is a string from a file being looped through. However the negative look behind just doesn't seem to work.

Here's the full script for context:

```
import sys
import fileinput
import os
import os.path
import re

# Descriptions: iterates over files in source directory, removes whitespace characters and saves to destination directory.


print ('Source Directory:', str(sys.argv[1]))
print ('Destination Directory:', str(sys.argv[2]))

for i in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    fullSource = (os.path.join(sys.argv[1], i))
    fullDestination = (os.path.join(sys.argv[2], i))
    newfile = open(fullDestination, "x")
    for line in fileinput.input(fullSource):
        matchObj = re.search('(?<!\r)\n', line)
        if matchObj:
            newfile.write(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
        else:
            newfile.write(line)
    newfile.close
    print ("created " + fullDestination)
```

The result is all returns (both CR and CRLF) are removed.
Am I missing something?

Comment: `\r` = `CR`, not `LF` and `(?<!\r)\n` pattern matches `\n` that are not preceded with `\r`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/2nvBVB) - it works.

Comment: apologies, I was getting my \r \n characters mixed up. I've edited the question now.

Comment: Yes, but your code works. Please show the "bigger picture" (more related code).

Comment: You speak of a file... How are your opening and reading it?

Comment: To just match the standalone newlines your look behind won't work when the line only contains a single `\n` (blank line).  Try:  `(?:^|[^\r])\n`.  You also probably need `flags=re.MULTILINE`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - just added the surrounding script :)

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Just added the surrounding script with file opening lies included :)

Comment: But you are not replacing anything, `re.search` only searches for the linebreaks. You need `re.sub`. You do not even need to check if any line matches the pattern, just use `re.sub("(?<!\r)\n", "", line)` (if you plan to remove the standalone LFs.).

Comment: This reminds me of a recent request where a similar thing happened in R. I'll repeat what I said there: is it possible that the `\r` and `\n` in your source code already get translated to literal characters **before** being handed over to the regex parser? If so, double the backslashes so the regex parser receives a **literal** string "\r" (which it should parse per common regex rules) instead of the code for a CR (and likewise for the LF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this result is no surprise. `fileinput` module opens the files in text mode, by default, so `\r\n` are automatically changed in single `\n`. So the regex matches every line and removes all the `\n` - the `\r` have already been removed by `fileinput`.

So you must explicitely use a binary open mode. Unfortunately if you use Python 3.x (what your `print` syntax suggests), binary mode gives you bytes that you need to translate to strings. Your code could become:

```
import sys
import fileinput
import os
import os.path
import re

# Descriptions: iterates over files in source directory, removes whitespace characters and saves to destination directory.


print ('Source Directory:', str(sys.argv[1]))
print ('Destination Directory:', str(sys.argv[2]))

for i in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
    fullSource = (os.path.join(sys.argv[1], i))
    fullDestination = (os.path.join(sys.argv[2], i))
    newfile = open(fullDestination, "x")
    for line in fileinput.input(fullSource, mode='rb'):  # explicite binary mode
        line = line.decode('latin1')   # convert to string in Python3
        matchObj = re.search('(?<!\r)\n', line)
        if matchObj:
            newfile.write(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
        else:
            newfile.write(line)
    newfile.close
    print ("created " + fullDestination)
```

Comment: Awesome, nice one :) This just about got me there except on writing the file I got an extra \r on every line so I decided to write back to the file in binary too (i.e. I did an "open(fullDestination, 'xb')" and then passed a line.encode to the .write and all was good :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correctly matching `\n` character that are not preceded by `\r`:

```
>>> re.search('(?<!\r)\n', 'abc\r')
>>> re.search('(?<!\r)\n', 'abc\r\n')
>>> re.search('(?<!\r)\n', 'abc\n')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(3, 4), match='\n'>
```

Your `if` and `write` are wrong:

```
if matchObj:  # "If line ends with '\n'"
    # Won't strip anything, because line ends with '\n', not '\r\n'.
    newfile.write(line.rstrip('\r\n'))
else:
    newfile.write(line)
```

You probably want to do something like this:

```
if not matchObj:  # "If line ends with '\r\n'"
    # Note that strip('\r\n') removes these two characters, but does not add '\n' back.
    newfile.write(line.replace('\r\n', '\n'))
else:
    newfile.write(line)
```

By the way, you don't need regular expressions to do what you want, `endswith()` should suffice:

```
if line.endswith('\r\n'):
    newfile.write(line.replace('\r\n', '\n'))
else:
    newfile.write(line)
```

Actually, `replace()` itself is more than enough:

```
newfile.write(line.replace('\r\n', '\n'))
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta: then I have not understood the question